# Insert into static hive partition using Presto

Tags: sql, hive, presto, trino, hive-partitions

Suppose I want to `INSERT INTO` a static hive partition, can I do that with `Presto`?

The `PARTITION` keyword is only for hive.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE Employee PARTITION (department='HR')
```

> Caused by: com.facebook.presto.sql.parser.ParsingException: line 1:44:
>   mismatched input 'PARTITION'. Expecting: '(',  at
>   com.facebook.presto.sql.parser.ErrorHandler.syntaxError(ErrorHandler.java:109)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [Presto](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/insert.html) you do not need PARTITION(department='HR').

```
INSERT INTO Employee (name, department)
VALUES  ('John', 'HR');
```

or

```
INSERT INTO Employee (name, department)
select 
      name, 
      'HR' 
from 
...
```

Comment: INSERT INTO  is good enough. TABLE clause is not needed

Comment: This works, everybody. Make sure to use single quotes in presto, I just spent several minutes trying to figure out what didn't work, turns out presto didn't like double quotes.